# 透明なJFrameに日本語入力すると背景が白くなります。

Tags: java

JFrameを透明にした状態でJTextAreaに日本語入力するとフレームが白くなります。
１度白くなると再表示しない限り白いままです。どなたかこの現象の回避方法知りませんか？

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame =new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(670,500);
    frame.setLocation(600,420);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);                             
    frame.setBackground(new Color(0x00000000, true));       
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextArea text=new JTextArea();
    text.setBackground(Color.RED);
    text.setBounds(85, 120, 265, 240);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(text);
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    content.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

環境：windows7　java8

Answer (score 2):

本家SOに類似質問と[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15866690/8248751)がありました。

その回答によるとSwingにおけるDirectDrawパイプラインのバグに起因する現象のようです。
DirectDrawレンダリングを無効化することで、質問の現象を回避できました。

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true"); //この行を追加
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //以下同じ
    //省略
}
```

上記は手っ取り早い解決方法です。
個別の`JTextArea`に対してDirectDrawを無効化したい場合は、`JTextArea`を継承して`paintComponent`をオーバーライドするコードが本家SOの回答を参照してください。